# Error in expression regular with preg_match 3

Tags: php

```
<td><strong>Puesto:</strong></td>
<td>PUESTO CABECERA MUNICIPAL                                                                                               </td>
```

I'm have this expression regular

`preg_match("%<td><strong>Puesto:</strong></td><td>(.*)<\/td>%si",$data,$puesto);` 
but not it works

Comment: what out put you want?

Comment: Undefined offset: 1 in the echo $puesto[1];

Comment: You need to edit your question and make it clear what you are wanting. It is currently *unclear*.

Comment: You don't have the closing `<td>` in your example, so it wouldn't match. As aside, you shouldn't be parsing HTML with regex. *Edit:* oh wait, its just way out on the gas. Still don't do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want this:

```
$ok = preg_match('%<strong>Puesto:</strong>.+?<td>(.+?)</td>%si', $data, $puesto);
```

Don't forget to use `?` to make expressions into non-greedy!

Comment: Perfect, thank you, and the qualification to my question was of - 3 point, it seems unfair it, there is question minus interesting and not have qualification bad